# Как сделать текст у checkbox'а зачёркнутым?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Привет всем!
Есть такой чекбокс

```
CheckBox  todo = new CheckBox(this);
todo.setText(task);
```

где task - это просто строка, например, "магазин"

вопрос - как можно сделать текст этого чекбокса зачёркнутым по нажатию?
(слушатель уже на нём висит, я просто не могу понять\найти - как зачеркнуть текст, когда я поставил галочку)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам нужно в слушателе, если была поставлена галочка, из текста чекбокса создавать объект `SpannableString`, задавая ему стиль зачёркнутой строки. Потом передавать этот объект в чекбокс методом `setText`.

```
SpannableString string = new SpannableString(todo.getText());
string.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 0, string.length(), 0);
todo.setText(string);
```

[Источник.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30104149/7485582)

Answer (score 2):

Так как `CheckBox` является наследником `TextView`, то зачеркнуть текст можно с помощью `Paint` флагов:

```
CheckBox  todo = new CheckBox(this);
todo.setText(task);

todo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        if (isChecked) {    // Устанавливаем флаг зачёркивания
            buttonView.setPaintFlags(buttonView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);    

        } else {    // Убираем флаг зачёркивания
            buttonView.setPaintFlags(buttonView.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));    
        }
    }
});
```